# Nix error: undefined variable 'goPackages'

Tags: nix

I'm trying to build a docker image as described here: http://lethalman.blogspot.com/2016/04/cheap-docker-images-with-nix_15.html

default.nix

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;
let
  entrypoint = writeScript "entrypoint.sh" ''
    #!${stdenv.shell}
    set -e

    # allow the container to be started with `--user`
    if [ "$1" = "redis-server" -a "$(${coreutils}/bin/id -u)" = "0" ]; then
      chown -R redis .
      exec ${goPackages.gosu.bin}/bin/gosu redis "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
    fi

    exec "$@"
  '';
in
dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "redis";
  runAsRoot = ''
    #!${stdenv.shell}
    ${dockerTools.shadowSetup}
    groupadd -r redis
    useradd -r -g redis -d /data -M redis
    mkdir /data
    chown redis:redis /data
  '';

  contents = [ redis ];

  config = {
    Cmd = [ "redis-server" ];
    Entrypoint = [ entrypoint ];
    ExposedPorts = {
      "6379/tcp" = {};
    };
    WorkingDir = "/data";
    Volumes = {
      "/data" = {};
    };
  };
}
```

However this gives an error of:

```
nix-build
error: undefined variable 'goPackages' at /home/chris/temp/nix/default.nix:12:14
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gosu` is now available at: `${pkgs.gosu.bin}`

In other words, replace:

```
      exec ${goPackages.gosu.bin}/bin/gosu redis "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

With:

```
      exec ${pkgs.gosu.bin}/bin/gosu redis "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

**If anyone knows what happened to `goPackages` that would be useful to know.**

*I'm posting this question/answer as I think others might run into the same error.*